# Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-io, select-into

We are trying to export data from an Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL database to an S3 buckets.  The code being used is like this:

```
SELECT  *  FROM analytics.my_test INTO OUTFILE S3
  's3-us-east-2://myurl/sampledata'         
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
MANIFEST ON
OVERWRITE ON;
```

All permissions have been set up but we get the error

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTO"  Position: 55

Does this only work with a MySQL database?

Answer (score 3):

It is fairly new feature on Aurora Postgres, but it is possible to export the query result into a file on s3: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html#postgresql-s3-export-file

The syntax is not the same as for MySQL though. For Postgres it is:

```
SELECT * from aws_s3.query_export_to_s3('select * from sample_table', 
   aws_commons.create_s3_uri('sample-bucket', 'sample-filepath', 'us-west-2') 
);
```

Comment: is it asynchronous?

Answer (score 2):

I believe saving SQL select output data in S3 **ONLY works for Amazon Aurora MySQL DB.** I don't see any reference in the official documentation that mentions the same for Amazon Aurora PostgresSQL.

Here are snippets from official documentation that I referred to

[Integrating Amazon Aurora MySQL with Other AWS Services](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.html)

> Amazon Aurora MySQL integrates with other AWS services so that you can
>   extend your Aurora MySQL DB cluster to use additional capabilities in
>   the AWS Cloud. Your Aurora MySQL DB cluster can use AWS services to do
>   the following:
>
> Synchronously or asynchronously invoke an AWS Lambda function using
>   the native functions lambda_sync or lambda_async. For more
>   information, see Invoking a Lambda Function with an Aurora MySQL
>   Native Function.
>
> Load data from text or XML files stored in an Amazon Simple Storage
>   Service (Amazon S3) bucket into your DB cluster using the LOAD DATA
>   FROM S3 or LOAD XML FROM S3 command. For more information, see Loading
>   Data into an Amazon Aurora MySQL DB Cluster from Text Files in an
>   Amazon S3 Bucket.
>
> **Save data to text files stored in an Amazon S3 bucket from your DB
>   cluster using the SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3 command. For more
>   information, see Saving Data from an Amazon Aurora MySQL DB Cluster
>   into Text Files in an Amazon S3 Bucket.**
>
> Automatically add or remove Aurora Replicas with Application Auto
>   Scaling. For more information, see Using Amazon Aurora Auto Scaling
>   with Aurora Replicas.

[Integrating Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL with Other AWS Services](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Integrating.html)

> Amazon Aurora integrates with other AWS services so that you can
>   extend your Aurora PostgreSQL DB cluster to use additional
>   capabilities in the AWS Cloud. Your Aurora PostgreSQL DB cluster can
>   use AWS services to do the following:
>
> Quickly collect, view, and assess performance for your Aurora
>   PostgreSQL DB instances with Amazon RDS Performance Insights.
>   Performance Insights expands on existing Amazon RDS monitoring
>   features to illustrate your database's performance and help you
>   analyze any issues that affect it. With the Performance Insights
>   dashboard, you can visualize the database load and filter the load by
>   waits, SQL statements, hosts, or users.
>
> For more information about Performance Insights, see Using Amazon RDS
>   Performance Insights.
>
> Automatically add or remove Aurora Replicas with Aurora Auto Scaling.
>   For more information, see Using Amazon Aurora Auto Scaling with Aurora
>   Replicas.
>
> Configure your Aurora PostgreSQL DB cluster to publish log data to
>   Amazon CloudWatch Logs. CloudWatch Logs provide highly durable storage
>   for your log records. With CloudWatch Logs, you can perform real-time
>   analysis of the log data, and use CloudWatch to create alarms and view
>   metrics. For more information, see Publishing Aurora PostgreSQL Logs
>   to Amazon CloudWatch Logs.

Ther is no mention of saving data to S3 for PostgresSQL