# Is there a way to get a copy of an Amazon aurora postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I wanted to create a copy of our Amazon Aurora Postgresql database. According to what i can find in the documentation the reason why I can't export it to an S3 Bucket is because its enginemode is serverless instead of provisioned.

Similarly, I don't seem to be able to change the enginemode. At least the [documentation for modify-db-cluster](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/modify-db-cluster.html) dosen't seem to offer any options for that.

According to the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58599075/amazon-aurora-postgresql-select-into-outfile-s3) "Select into outfile" dosen't seem to be a possibility either.

I have also tried to follow [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html#postgresql-s3-export-file) but without any luck, composite types isn't supported.

Is there any way to get a dump of the content of a AWS Aurora PostgreSQL Serverless cluster?

Comment: You can always connect to the database and [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) it

Comment: Thanks! Would mark as correct answer if it wasen't only a comment. Please take buckets of gratitude instead!